# Why guard uses cpu almost 100%?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, guard

I've started to use [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) to monitor my testing changes, but is using so much cpu (between 80%~95% of CPU). I'm using it in conjuction with all these guard gems

```
gem "guard-rspec"
gem 'guard-livereload'
gem 'guard-rails-assets'
gem 'guard-bundler'
```

I though maybe is just my laptop, but other coworkers use them in their new laptops(newer than mine) and is using about 60~70% of cpu all the time.
I've tried to just run guard without all the other gems but the result is the same.

Is there a way to configure it and minimize their cpu usage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can tweak Guard to be more efficient by

1. Enable OS file system notifications as described in [efficient filesystem handling](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Efficient-Filesystem-Handling).
2. Ignore directories that are not of interest with the [ignore](https://github.com/guard/guard#ignore) DSL method.
3. Filter changes to file types of interest with the [filter](https://github.com/guard/guard#ignore) DSL method.

On my 2012 27" iMac watching a large Rails project with many active Guard plugins, the Guard process takes 0.01% of CPU time when listening to file changes.

Comment: +1 for the *efficient filesystem handling* link... using the OS notifications will make an astronomical difference, as guard falls back on continuous polling of file modification time.